# emacs ess and R no longer stable

Tags: r, macos, emacs, ess

I just got a new macbook pro and have R crashing from emacs within 10-20 minutes of using it each time with the same error:

> 2017-12-04 11:11:19.505 R[1009:29548] IMKInputSession [0x7fab1e93ea90
>   presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:completionHandler:] :
>   [self textInputContext]=0x0 *NO* NSRemoteViewController to client,
>   NSError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection from pid
>   0" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection from pid 0},
>   com.apple.inputmethod.EmojiFunctionRowItem

Seeing that .EmojiFunctionRowItem there makes me think it is from this silly touchbar. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: doesn't look like an ess related problem, does it happen if you run R in terminal/gui?

Comment: @jenesaisquoi yes, it has happened (once only) when I run it from iterm as well so perhaps it is simply an R thing?

Comment: @jenesaisquoi any idea on how to deal with this?

Comment: no, sorry I use linux

Comment: Seems like recent updates to macOS have fixed this issues...